# Should my OpenPGP key used for storing documents in the cloud expire?

Tags: encryption, gnupg, public-key-encryption, openpgp

I plan on doing a mass migration of all my local files to various cloud services since space is pretty cheap these days.

I figure I should probably encrypt my data before I upload it, which is better than just sending out there awaiting some data hack etc.  I've installed gpgtools on my Mac, and created a key pair, and now I can encrypt my files fairly easily.

However, when creating the key, there is an option to expire it.  I've done various googling about what this means, and it seems like it's a way to automatically revoke a public key for others if they were using it to encrypt messages.  Is this correct?  Also, does this even matter in my example as I'm only using my keys to encrypt files to be stored in the cloud?  I didn't set an expiry at all, but is there a reason why I should?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend the expiration date of (your own) keys as you wish by setting a new one, even after it actually expired. For this reason, setting an expiry date does not increase security against stolen keys. Regarding decryption of already encrypted files, this is irrelevant anyway as "the math" does not care for the expired key, nor do the implementations of OpenPGP.

The only advantage is "lost" keys (you haven't got a revocation certificate, uploaded the key to the key server network and lost the private key) expire after some time and don't stay on the key servers forever.

For a more in-depth discussion, have a look at "[Does GPG key expiration add to security?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14718/does-gpg-key-expiration-add-to-security/79386#79386)".